# Unique issue with a Sharepoint Site

Tags: 2007, error, site, rename

We have a SharePoint site and for some reason one of the sub site admins change the URL of their site from /sitename to sitename.aspx.  This has broken everything for that site I can not even get into the _layouts/settings for that site to change it.  I have tried using a backup and restore to rename it however the backup method thinks its a page and not a site and will not back it up.  I have also tried to export and import.  The export seems to work but the import gives a error:

```
4/23/2013 1:23:19 PM]: Start Time: 4/23/2013 1:23:19 PM.
[4/23/2013 1:23:19 PM]: Progress: Initializing Import.
[4/23/2013 1:23:20 PM]: Warning: Import requirement file  
C:\backup\Requirements.xml     was not found no verifications ran.
[4/23/2013 1:23:20 PM]: FatalError: There is an error in XML document (0, 0).
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String 

encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.DeserializeExportSettings()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.Run()
*** Inner exception:
Root element is missing.
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowWithoutLineInfo(String res)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read()
at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderSPExportSettings.Read11_ExportSettings()
[4/23/2013 1:23:20 PM]: Progress: Import Completed.
[4/23/2013 1:23:20 PM]: Finish Time: 4/23/2013 1:23:20 PM.
[4/23/2013 1:23:20 PM]: Completed with 1 warnings.
[4/23/2013 1:23:20 PM]: Completed with 1 errors.
```

I am all out of ideas any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the actual STSADM Command renameWeb (for the actual sub-site - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263508(v=office.12).aspx) or renameSite (for a site collection - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263038(v=office.12).aspx).

Comment: I've been in SP2010 so long I completely forgot about STSADM!!! /facepalm

Comment: No need Dave, it happens to the best of us! Cheers

Comment: stsadm cammand work thanks I will look into powershell alittle bit more but we are planning to upgrade pretty soon so probally will just wait for the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell to the rescue!  Try this:

**SharePoint 2010**

```
Get-SPWeb http://some.domain/PathTo/SiteUrl.aspx | Set-SPWeb -RelativeUrl SiteUrl
```

**SharePoint 2007**
**note: this is pseudocode as I do not have a SP2007 environment to test this on.  It should be pretty close though*

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")

$site = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite]("http://some.domain/")

$web = $site.OpenWeb("/PathTo/SiteUrl.aspx")

$web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $true #this might not be needed but is here just in case
$web.ServerRelativeUrl = "SiteUrl" # verify the current URL to see if more of the path is needed
$web.Update()

$web.Dispose()
$site.Dispose()
```

Comment: using MOSS 2007 dont have powershell installed.

Comment: You could use PowerShell even on MOSS 2007 - an example to read http://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2007/09/03/preparing-powershell-for-sharepoint-and-moss-2007/

Comment: You can still use Powershell with SP2007, you just don't get the nifty 2010 cmdlets.  PowerShell is a free download and can be installed without even having to restart the server.  I *strongly* recommend it as it will open a lot of doors for you

Comment: Use the STSADM approach @C.Marius suggests in his answer but you should still get PowerShell v.2 installed on your SP2007 servers for future maintenance and administration.